# How to handle unsupported datatypes in Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

It is known that some of datatypes like Float are not supported by Aerospike server. But they are handled at client side. For example Python client from version 1.0.40 supports unsupported datatypes using serialization.

I would like to know how exactly this is handled by the client while retrieving the data from server. I mean how the client knows the bin should be unserialized and render to the user.

This will help me to handle from outside the client if the client language I am using is not supporting this feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Anything other than the standard datatypes, will be stored as python blob (an internal datatype). Python's serialization mechanism is used to generate the bytes. Aerospike clients send the fact that it is sending a python blob. Aerospike server also stores this fact and return the info back when the bin is read. This is interpreted by the client and if its a python blob type, it runs the bytes through python's deserializer. This will reconstruct the python object. Similar thing is done in Java too and stored as java blob using java's serializer/deserializer.

Obviously, these python blobs cannot be read in a java client or vice versa. So, do not expect cross language functionality when using non-native types.

Comment: @ Sunil, thanks for your valuable reply. Can you please explain how to send the "fact" you mentioned to aerospike server and while reading back, how to read the fact. Will be helpful if you could explain in detail.

- Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone help me out for the above query?  How exactly I need to handle the "fact" which Sunil mentioned above.

Comment: You need not do anything explicitly. The Aerospike client driver handles this transparently. The client driver is open sourced if you want to take a look at it. But I dont recommend customizing it too much.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization in the Python client is explained in more details in a section right above the [set_serializer](https://pythonhosted.org/aerospike/aerospike.html#aerospike.set_serializer) method

Comment: @ Ronen. Thanks for your reply.  I have went through that and I am not able to get what I need.

I need to know on the deserialization part. I how it is known that the bin should be deserialized and returned to the user or it should be returned as blob without deserialization. There can be a situation where I have inserted some blob and expect the blob back without deserialization.  Can you please explain this area in detail?  Thanks.

Comment: If you're not setting your own serializer, then a bytearray will save as as_bytes with encoding AS_BYTES_BLOB. When you read that record (if you haven't set a deserializer) any AS_BYTES_BLOB will turn back into a bytearray. Similarly, the default serializer will turn unsupported types into as_bytes with encoding AS_BYTES_PYTHON, and when the Python client reads those it deserializes back to the original Python type. I hope that answers you.

Comment: @ Ronen. Thanks for your reply. I think this flow has been implemented in C client and python client wrapped around C client doesnt know this. Is there a way to get the encoding type whether it is AS_BYTES_BLOB or AS_BYTES_PYTHON from python client?

Comment: If you're using the built-in cPickle-based serialization you can rely on the types to implicitly figure out the encoding . If you get back a bytearray it means the type on the server was as_bytes with encoding AS_BYTES_BLOB. If it's any other type that means it is AS_BYTES_PYTHON, which will trigger automatic deserialization. Otherwise there is no way to know from within Python.